# Command line arguments are not working in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

--A_Z_Handwritten Data.csv: The path to the Kaggle A-Z dataset (Lines 3 and 4)
--HandWritingRecognition: The path to output the trained handwriting recognition model (Lines 5 and 6)

---

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-a", "--A_Z_Handwritten Data.csv", required=True,
        help="path to A-Z dataset")
    ap.add_argument("-m", "--HandWritingRecognition", type=str, required=True,
        help="path to output trained handwriting recognition mode")
    # ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    #   help="/home/gaurav/Desktop/HandWritingRecognition/")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

---

This is the error...!

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -a A_Z_HANDWRITTEN DATA.CSV -m
                             HANDWRITINGRECOGNITION
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -a/--A_Z_Handwritten Data.csv, -m/--HandWritingRecognition
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: Could you describe what you want an invokation of your program to look like?

Comment: I am trying to construct the argument parser and parse the arguments. By the way, this is the handwrittentext recognition code.

Comment: What are you running in the command line?